# VBA vlookup using Excel reference table in external workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Right now, I'm using this type of code to look at what's in column O to determine what to enter in column N. Since the data is confidential, I'm just making it letters and numbers here. It works fine, but instead of hardcoding the cases in the VBA code, I want it to reference a table that is in an external workbook because I'm going to have thousands of cases and values to insert.

```
Sub ChangeTest()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
      LastRow = Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      For i = 2 To LastRow
        Select Case Range("O" & i)
          Case "A", "B", "C"
            Range("N" & i) = "1"
          Case "D","E","F"
            Range("N" & i) = "2"
          Case "G","H","I"
            Range("N" & i) = "3"
        End Select
      Next i
End Sub
```

In the external workbook, column D will contain the cases (A, B, C, etc.) and column C will have the number (1, 2, 3, etc.) that is to go into column N in the original workbook.

I'm not sure if the code I have now needs to be edited slightly to incorporate the reference table or if it's going to need to be completely different.

Comment: Perhaps this can help: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/vba-vlookup-of-external-workbook/68df21ca-40bb-4b7c-bc77-a0cff6771d4d

Comment: Will the external workbook already be open?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just run a vlookup like you title suggests instead of running a loop?:

```
Sub ChangeTest()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Referance_Workbook As Workbook
Dim Referance_Tab As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range


Set Referance_Workbook = Workbooks.Open("[Referance workbook path]")
Set Referance_Tab = Referance_Workbook.Sheets("[Referance tab within referance workbook]")
Referance_Workbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

LastRow = Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Range("N2:N" & LastRow)
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-11],'[Source Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!C1:C2,2,0),""No in refrence table"")"


End Sub
```

This does a lookup on column A of you reference workbook/tab and looks for a result in column B

Comment: I think I made the correct changes, but I'm getting a "subscript out of range" error for the Set Referance_Tab value. If the tab is called RData, shouldn't that be what is in the brackets on that line? Like this? `Set Referance_Tab = Referance_Workbook.Sheets("[RData]")`

Comment: Nope, it should be `Set Referance_Tab = Referance_Workbook.Sheets("RData")`

Comment: I'm not getting the error, but it's still not working right. This is what my last line looks like. I think I don't have something in right. Also, it should be doing a lookup on column D and look for a result in column C. `Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-11],'[otherworkbook.xlsm]RData'!C:D,1,0),""No in refrence table"")"`

Comment: You can't do a vlookup on a column to the left hand side of the column you're looking up - you need an Index-Match formula. Change `Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-11],'[otherworkbook.xlsm]RData'!C:D,1,‌​0),""No in refrence table"")"` to `Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX('[otherworkbook.xlsm]RData'!C3:C4,MATCH(RC[-11],'[[otherworkbook.xlsm]RData'!C4,0),1),""Not in reference table"")"`

Comment: It's giving me the "Not in reference table" error for all rows. The formula should be comparing what's in column O in the original workbook to what's in column D in the reference workbook.

Comment: My bad - I had it in my head you were checking column C - here's what should be in there: `Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX('[otherworkbook.xlsm]RData'!C3:C4,MATCH(RC[1],'[[otherworkbook‌​.xlsm]RData'!C4,0),1‌​),""Not in reference table"")"`

Comment: Wait. Sorry. I see another thing that I'm doing wrong. I'm not going to know what the source workbook name is going to be. This code will need to be ran on many different workbooks. How can I get around not giving the filename for the source workbook?

Comment: If it makes it easier, I think I will be able to swap columns C and D in the reference workbook, so I'll be able to use vlookup.

Comment: Also, Sheet1 may not be the name of the tab in the source workbook, but it will always be ran in the first tab.